# google maps api can't find one specific address

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am using google maps api and it works for all but one specific address. It's "99p Stores 19-20 Market Place Wisbech PE13 1DZ". When using google maps I can find it, but using js api it says 'zero results'.

My code:

```
function mapsSetMark(map, address) {
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function (results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setZoom(13);
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
    } else {
        console.log('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 3):

"99p Stores 19-20 Market Place Wisbech PE13 1DZ" is a place not a postal address.  The [Geocoder is specifically for **postal addresses**](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding)

It can find "19-20 Market Place Wisbech PE13 1DZ"

To find "99p Stores 19-20 Market Place Wisbech PE13 1DZ" use the [Places API Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places)