# GoogleMaps API is giving out manchester address instead of Piccadilly Circus, London, UK

Tags: json, google-maps

The following http request gives out manchester location instead of the actual Picadilly Circus address in London:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Piccadilly Circus, London, UK

Nevertheless, when I search for "Piccadilly Circus, London, UK" in GoogleMaps I get the correct location in the map.

Below is the resulting JSON obtained from the API call:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "address_components": [
        {
          "long_name": "Piccadilly",
          "short_name": "Piccadilly",
          "types": [
            "establishment",
            "point_of_interest"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "London Rd",
          "short_name": "London Rd",
          "types": [
            "route"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Manchester",
          "short_name": "Manchester",
          "types": [
            "locality",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Manchester",
          "short_name": "Manchester",
          "types": [
            "postal_town"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "Greater Manchester",
          "short_name": "Greater Manchester",
          "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_2",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "England",
          "short_name": "England",
          "types": [
            "administrative_area_level_1",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "",
          "short_name": "GB",
          "types": [
            "country",
            "political"
          ]
        },
        {
          "long_name": "M60",
          "short_name": "M60",
          "types": [
            "postal_code"
          ]
        }
      ],
      "formatted_address": "Piccadilly, London Rd, Manchester M60",
      "geometry": {
        "location": {
          "lat": 53.4771243,
          "lng": -2.2310505
        },
        "location_type": "APPROXIMATE",
        "viewport": {
          "northeast": {
            "lat": 53.4784732802915,
            "lng": -2.229701519708498
          },
          "southwest": {
            "lat": 53.4757753197085,
            "lng": -2.232399480291502
          }
        }
      },
      "partial_match": true,
      "place_id": "ChIJ9flXEJaxe0gRpCvy-ySgeBs",
      "types": [
        "establishment",
        "light_rail_station",
        "point_of_interest",
        "transit_station"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "status": "OK"
}
```

Comment: You need to use the places API for places (like "Piccadilly Circus, London, UK"), the geocoding API only works reliably for **postal** addresses.

Comment: possible duplicate of [google maps api can't find one specific address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34727425/google-maps-api-cant-find-one-specific-address)

Comment: possible duplicate of [google map marker is not pinning properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34781932/google-map-marker-is-not-pinning-properly)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google maps API geocoding returns same coordinates for two different places](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33982946/google-maps-api-geocoding-returns-same-coordinates-for-two-different-places)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in the search keys, in fact the following request

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Piccadilly%20Circus%20Station,%20London,%20UK

get a correct answer

```
{
   "results" : [
      {
         "address_components" : [
            {
               "long_name" : "Piccadilly Circus Station",
               "short_name" : "Piccadilly Circus Station",
               "types" : [ "establishment", "point_of_interest" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Piccadilly Circus",
               "short_name" : "Piccadilly Circus",
               "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "London",
               "short_name" : "London",
               "types" : [ "postal_town" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Greater London",
               "short_name" : "Greater London",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_2", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "England",
               "short_name" : "England",
               "types" : [ "administrative_area_level_1", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "Regno Unito",
               "short_name" : "GB",
               "types" : [ "country", "political" ]
            },
            {
               "long_name" : "W1J 9HP",
               "short_name" : "W1J 9HP",
               "types" : [ "postal_code" ]
            }
         ],
         "formatted_address" : "Piccadilly Circus Station, London W1J 9HP, Regno Unito",
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 51.510121,
               "lng" : -0.1341683
            },
            "location_type" : "APPROXIMATE",
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 51.51146998029149,
                  "lng" : -0.132819319708498
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 51.50877201970849,
                  "lng" : -0.135517280291502
               }
            }
         },
         "place_id" : "ChIJvVRe4NMEdkgRw3WgQO_J9KM",
         "types" : [
            "establishment",
            "point_of_interest",
            "train_station",
            "transit_station"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

Comment: Correct! The address "Piccadilly Circus, London, UK" needed to be encoded... Thanks for your help!

Comment: you're welcome, Gustavo. If you found my answer useful, please accept it and happy coding!